# Dynamic meta robots

Tags: php

I am trying to find the best way to create a dynamic meta robots section. I have a search engine and only want the main search "with all categories searched together" indexed by google and others. I want any category searches to be NOINDEX so I do not get duplication penalties for possibly having alot of the same text showing on a different search page. I made it so if "category" is in the url to make it NOINDEX like this.

```
<?php if (!isset($_GET['category'])) echo "<meta name='robots' content='all'>"; if (isset($_GET['category'])) echo "<META NAME='ROBOTS' CONTENT='NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW'>"; ?>
```

It seems to work fine this, it makes the normal search have this meta robots

```
<meta name="robots" content="all">
```

And if any category is searched the meta robots look like this

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

Just wondering if this the best way to do this? Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

EDIT:
I am assuming that since no one has replied that this is the way to go. Hope this possibly helps someone else someday. Thanks for viewing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `noindex` is the right way to prevent search engines from indexing that specific page.

But why are you using `nofollow`? You tell the search engine to *not follow the links on that page*. Is there a reason why you're doing that? If not, you could remove the `nofollow` part.

Comment: Yeah I could no follow page links. I just threw it in there so that I don't have to nofollow pagination and such.

Answer (score 1):

yes, this is fine way to do it. I see no problem in that.